# Receiving cookies from ajax on blackberry

Tags: javascript, ajax, blackberry, cookies

In most (all) browsers when I make an ajax request, and the server sends some cookies with the response, they will then be sent with future requests.

This seems not to happen on blackberry 4.6.

The `getResponseHeader('Set-Cookie')` function shows the cookie, although only one even if the server sends multiple set-cookie functions.

Has anyone found anyway to make the blackberry browser accept the cookie?